# What does "in use" mean for an image?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

What does "in use" mean and how can I get that info from the CLI?

[image: docker images screenshot]

Reference: `docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.State}}\t{{.Image}}"`

| CONTAINER ID | NAMES | STATE | IMAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07bce6924796 | laughing_wozniak | exited | vsc-volume-bootstrap |
| 6d37d8744a77 | angry_brahmagupta | exited | vsc-quickstarts-d91f349952ba5208420f1403c31b2955-uid |
| 0bce117a827c | dapr_placement | running | daprio/dapr:1.5.0 |
| 1232bf715593 | dapr_zipkin | running | openzipkin/zipkin |
| c128e546a0b6 | dapr_redis | running | redis |
| dc44e1006831 | miked | exited | my-first-fsharp-web |
| ce3cf77a0eb9 | minikube | running | gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28 |

Reference: `docker image ls`

| REPOSITORY | TAG | IMAGE ID | CREATED | SIZE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vsc-microsoftvscodeinsiders-572e00dcd0f79c5ee8d7d39c18e7c701-features | latest | 9f05ea6535d4 | 12 hours ago | 6.36GB |
| vsc-volume-bootstrap | latest | 81646861762b | 12 hours ago | 180MB |
| vsc-quickstarts-d91f349952ba5208420f1403c31b2955-uid | latest | 453bd2943e10 | 40 hours ago | 9.7GB |
| vsc-quickstarts-d91f349952ba5208420f1403c31b2955 | latest | 10de525681a7 | 40 hours ago | 9.7GB |
| openzipkin/zipkin | latest | 6a9714eacfd9 | 2 days ago | 153MB |
| miked.azurecr.io/my-first-fsharp-web |  | 96e7948ee30c | 5 days ago | 211MB |
| my-first-fsharp-web | latest | e36fabe64a1c | 5 days ago | 211MB |
| miked.azurecr.io/my-first-fsharp-web | 1 | e36fabe64a1c | 5 days ago | 211MB |
| miked.azurecr.io/my-first-fsharp-web | latest | e36fabe64a1c | 5 days ago | 211MB |
| counter-image | latest | 22dfe0305c55 | 7 days ago | 208MB |
| redis | latest | 40c68ed3a4d2 | 8 days ago | 113MB |
| daprio/dapr | 1.5.0 | bff1855a0302 | 2 weeks ago | 214MB |
| vsc-azure-container-apps-demo-41dcd784881293406771e08c255554b9 | latest | 1af591496e8a | 4 weeks ago | 337MB |
| gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase | v0.0.28 | e2a6c047bedd | 8 weeks ago | 1.08GB |

Comment: Compare the images highlighted as "in use" with the Image column in your list of containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It indicates if the image is used by a container (running or already stopped).

You cannot get this via the CLI using `docker images`, but listing the containers `docker ps -a` you can see the associated image.